# free opensource amfphp alternative

Tags: php, apache-flex

is there any other framework that does the same as amfphp? I dont want to use amfphp because it hasnt been updated in years and looks like it's no longer under development, I have to use PHP so I'm looking for a PHP alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Zend_Amf`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html) class, which is part of Zend Framework, might interest you.

It's also available as a [standalone component](http://framework.zend.com/download/amf), if you don't want to full framework with it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this wikpedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) there are a two other PHP alternatives

[SabreAMF](http://osflash.org/sabreamf) and [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php)

SabreAMF is free and opensource